# FB.Canvas.getPageInfo not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am working on a FB app and used FB.Canvas.getPageInfo to get the scroll of the canvas to set popups in the screen center because the application is not scrolling but its the fb canvas which is scrolling and to find the center of the screen on long pages i need to get the number of pixels the canvas is scrolled and then with some plus minus i get the screen center of current page position. This was working fine till yesterday but is not since morning, I have tried alot but no success yet.

the code is called in `setTimeout` function, until the value is received I forcefully set my popup's dispaly to none and show a loader image.

remember it was working fine til last night

here is the code

```
$('.popup-call-local').live('click', function(event){

        //FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(info){alert(info.scrollTop);});
        var view_name = this.id;

        var check_view_name = view_name.replace(/_/g, '-');

        if($('#'+check_view_name).length > 0){
            $('#popupDiv').css('height',$('.wrap').css('height'));
            $('#popupDiv').css('display','block');
            $('#popupDiv').css('z-index',1000);
            var x = Number((window.screen.width - 400) / 2);
                var y = Number(event.pageY)+ 10;
                $('#popupDiv').html('<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/loaderblack.gif"  style="position:absolute; z-index:50000; left:'+x+'px; top:'+y+'px;" />');

            $('#'+check_view_name).css('z-index',2000);
            var viewportHeight = window.screen.height;
            var windowScrolled = -1;
        $foo = jQuery('#'+check_view_name),
        elWidth = $foo.width(),
        elHeight = $foo.height(),
        elOffset = $foo.offset();
        setTimeout(function(){FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(info){windowScrolled=info.scrollTop;  while(windowScrolled == -1){
            $('#'+check_view_name).css('display','none');}
            var v = (((viewportHeight - elHeight) / 2) + (windowScrolled) - 100); if(v<=0){v=Number(v)*Number(-1);}$('#popupDiv').html('');$('#'+check_view_name).css('display','block');$('#spinner').css('display','none');$('#'+check_view_name).css('top', Number(v) + 'px');});}, 3000);
        }else{

             return false;
        }
    });
```

EDIT
well

just found that its a facebook bug reported here
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/185097921606322?browse=search_4f60961cc946d7143000700